# Registration Form REST API Best Practices

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I'm building a SaaS application using the MEAN stack and have a few questions regarding how best to secure registration forms. Express.js is what I'm using to generate the endpoints (via angular-fullstack)

I have "tenants" that register using a registration form (name, email, password, etc.). This REST API is currently unsecured (POST /tenants).

My questions are:

1. Should I somehow secure this POST? If so, how?
2. If I'm not to secure the POST /tenants endpoint, how do I avoid someone writing a script to just create a whole bunch of tenants and attack my application?
3. I want to use some sort of confirmation email, but is that good practice when registering a new tenant?

I'd love to get some feedback here on how best to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: securing it through normal means (ssl) won't prevent a script creating a whole bunch of users, that's what captchas and honeypots are for. Email confirmation can combat this, but it also isn't fool proof. neither are captchas and honeypots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reCAPTCHA is the solution I chose to solve this same problem.

Quoting from [Google's developer site on reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) an overview of integrating reCAPTCHA into a site follow.  It's worth noting Google's reCAPTCHA codelab also includes an example for Java.

> **Overview**
>
> To start using reCAPTCHA, you need to [sign up for an API key](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) pair
>   for your site. The key pair consists of a site key and secret key. The
>   site key is used to invoke reCAPTCHA service on your site or mobile
>   application. The secret key authorizes communication between your
>   application backend and the reCAPTCHA server to [verify the user's
>   response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). The secret key needs to be kept safe for security
>   purposes.
>
> First, choose the [type of reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) and then fill in authorized
>   domains or [package names](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package). After you accept our terms of service,
>   you can click Register button to get new API key pair.
>
> Now please take the following steps to add reCAPTCHA to your site or
>   mobile application:
>
> 1. Choose the client side integration:
>
>    - [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)
>    - reCAPTCHA v2
>    - [Checkbox](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)
>    - [Invisible](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible)
>    - [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha.html)
> 2. [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

And being a Python fan, here's an example I followed to implement this solution in  Django (ref: [Google's codelab example](https://g.co/recaptcha/codelab)):

> **1. Getting set up**
>
> **Install and verify web server**
>
> This codelab can either be run locally or through the gcloud shell in
>   Google Cloud Platform. To get started with the gcloud shell go to
>   https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/start.
>
> **Download the Code**
>
> Clone all the code for this codelab:
>
> `git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/recaptcha-codelab.git`
>
> For Python:
>
> ```
> cd recaptcha-codelab/phase1-python
> python server.py
> ```
>
> In the web
>   browser, go to http://localhost:8080 to see the example UI without
>   reCAPTCHA integrated.
>
> **2. Registering with the reCAPTCHA Admin Console**
>
> ... We recommend if you have
>   time that you follow through and create your own registration in the
>   admin console. Before you use reCAPTCHA in development or production
>   you will need to do this step.
>
> First go to [The reCAPTCHA Admin Site](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).
>
> Choose ‘Invisible reCAPTCHA' as the type of captcha.
>   [image]
>
> Fill in the list of domains you wish to show your captcha. The reCAPTCHA site 
>   key you create will only work on these domains. Save the site key and
>   secret key for the later stages.
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> **3. Add Invisible reCAPTCHA to the frontend - Python**
>
> Let's update the frontend to call Invisible reCAPTCHA with your
>   favorite text editor.
>
> First let's add a script tag to the html  element in
>   feedback.html.
>
> **feedback.html**
>
> ```html
>  <html>
>  <head>
>    <title>Suggestion page</title>
>    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
> ```
>
> Now update the attributes to the submit button. Add
>   `class='g-recaptcha'` `data-sitekey="YOUR SITE KEY"` and add a
>   `data-callback`.
>
> **feedback.html**
>
> ```html
>      <button class="g-recaptcha"
>        data-sitekey="6LfeHx4UAAAAAAKUx5rO5nfKMtc9-syDTdFLftnm"
>        data-callback="onSubmit">Submit</button>
> ```
>
> The full file should be:
>
> **feedback.html**
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <title>Suggestion page</title>
>   <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
>   <script>
>     function onSubmit() {
>       document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
>     }   
>   </script>
>   <style>
>     body {
>       font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
>     }   
>     .status-message {
>       background-color: #5ff;
>       margin-bottom: 10px;
>       text-align: center;
>     }   
>     textarea {
>       margin: 10px 0;
>       resize: none;
>     }   
>   </style>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <h3>Give us feedback on our webpage!</h3>
>   <div class="status-message">%s</div>
>   <form id="demo-form" action="/feedback" method="POST">
>     Your comment <br><textarea name="feedback" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br>
>     <!-- Replace this with your site key --> 
>     <button class="g-recaptcha"
>             data-sitekey="6LfeHx4UAAAAAAKUx5rO5nfKMtc9-syDTdFLftnm"
>             data-callback="onSubmit">Submit</button>
>   </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> **3. Validate the Invisible reCAPTCHA on the Server - Python**
>
> In "Registering with the reCAPTCHA Admin Console" we created a new
>   site key. As part of that process a site secret was created. The site
>   secret is necessary to validate the CAPTCHA solution. For the purposes
>   of this code lab you can use the default keys provided. These will
>   only work on localhost.
>
> The validation of the reCAPTCHA token is done by sending a POST
>   request to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. The
>   details are in [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).
>
> To validate the reCAPTCHA token, let's update the server. First we
>   need to add the site secret and site verify constants.
>
> **server.py**
>
> ```py
> SITE_VERIFY_URL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
> SITE_SECRET = '6LfeHx4UAAAAAFWXGh_xcL0B8vVcXnhn9q_SnQ1b'
> RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_PARAM = 'g-recaptcha-response'
> ```
>
> Then we need to update our POST handler to verify the token.
>
> **server.py**
>
> ```py
> def do_POST(self):
>     self.set_headers();
>     post_body = parse_qs(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length'])))
>
>     success = False
>     if RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_PARAM in post_body:
>       token = post_body[RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_PARAM][0]
>       resp = urllib.urlopen(
>           SITE_VERIFY_URL, urllib.urlencode(
>               {'secret': SITE_SECRET, 'response': token}, True)).read()
>       if json.loads(resp).get("success"):
>         success = True
>
>     if success:
>       message = 'Thanks for the feedback!'
>     else:
>       message = 'There was an error.'
>     self.wfile.write(open(curdir + sep + 'feedback.html').read() % message)
> ```
>
> The final file should look like this:
>
> **server.py**
>
> ```py
> import json
> import urllib
> from os import curdir, sep
> from urlparse import parse_qs
> from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
>
> SITE_VERIFY_URL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
> SITE_SECRET = '6LfeHx4UAAAAAFWXGh_xcL0B8vVcXnhn9q_SnQ1b'
> RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_PARAM = 'g-recaptcha-response'
>
> class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
>   def set_headers(self):
>     self.send_response(200)
>     self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
>     self.end_headers()
>
>   def do_GET(self):
>     self.set_headers();
>     self.wfile.write(open(curdir + sep + 'feedback.html').read() % '')
>
>   def do_POST(self):
>     self.set_headers();
>     post_body = parse_qs(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length'])))
>
>     success = False
>     if RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_PARAM in post_body:
>       token = post_body[RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_PARAM][0]
>       resp = urllib.urlopen(
>           SITE_VERIFY_URL, urllib.urlencode(
>               {'secret': SITE_SECRET, 'response': token}, True)).read()
>       if json.loads(resp).get("success"):
>         success = True
>
>     if success:
>       message = 'Thanks for the feedback!'
>     else:
>       message = 'There was an error.'
>     self.wfile.write(open(curdir + sep + 'feedback.html').read() % message)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8080), Handler)
>   httpd.serve_forever()
> ```
>
> You're all done! Now reload the server and give it a try. The
>   completed version can be found in final-python/server.py. You now have
>   a basic integration with reCAPTCHA to protect your form. In the
>   background, we are verifying the user and will sometimes show a
>   reCAPTCHA challenge to make sure that your website is protected from
>   abuse. More details and options can be found on our [developer site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro).

**Please note:** I am an independant software developer with no affiliation with Google.

Comment: Marking this as the solution because this is what we ended up doing as well. In hindsight I should have updated this question with my solution.... but it's pretty old at this point :)

Answer (score 0):

You should review the Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) [website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) and their [Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) vulnerabilities thoroughly. There's a lot of information there. I also recommend abiding by their [cheat sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets#tab=Master_Cheat_Sheet). This resource is a helpful place to get started. Web security is complex and requires you to be comprehensive in your protection scheme.